# SignalR Hub listening for Entity Framework additions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr, subscribe

I tried looking for an existing question like this, but wasn't able to find one.

Basically, I want to implement an Activity Feed in my web application using SignalR, since I don't want to have to constantly poll a webservice if I don't have to. That seems pretty straightforward to me.

I'm planning to have an ActivityFeedItems table that holds those events. My thinking is that every time something is added to that table, I'll push a notification to all the clients of the SignalR Hub, and the client will populate the feed.

My question then is, is there a way to listen for EntityFramework adding an object of this type? Otherwise, I'll have to poll the table to see if there have been any new entries since the last time. While this is definitely doable, given the scale of our app, I'd prefer not to poll at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [How to: Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN. Seems like that might be a good place to do it.

Comment: Thanks. If you post this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as correct. That looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `SaveChanges()` method for your DbContext, as described at [How to: Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN.

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    //perform logic here
    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```

Comment: Would this require a singleton instance of the DbContext? I wasn't planning on only having one DbContext available, so I don't know if this'll work now that I think about it.

Comment: @Kith I don't think it needs to be a singleton. Should work fine if you have multiple instances of your context. Just make sure in your `SaveChanges()` implementation that you only broadcast if the entity has been modified or changed.